# Do different quantum fields of the same type have different creation and destruction operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, elementary-particles

[Context: I'm a math guy, self-studying QFT, using intro texts by Schwichtenberg, Klauber, Lancaster & Blundell; and also the web.  Long-time reader of StackExchange, first-time questioner.]

In QFT, (Real-valued) solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation are quantum fields given by
$$\varphi (x)=\int dk K \left [ a(\textbf{k})e^{ikx}+a^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})e^{-ikx} \right ]$$
with *K* the appropriate constant.
It looks like two distinct quantum fields $\varphi _{1}$ and $\varphi _{2}$ that solve K-G will in general have different associated creation and destruction operators, $a_{1}(\textbf{k})\neq a_{2}(\textbf{k})$ and $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\neq a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$.  That is, for a given 3-momentum $\textbf{k}$, there are different creation and destruction operators associated with different quantum fields.   Correct?

If so:

For a given $\textbf{k}$, and different quantum fields $\varphi _{1}$ and $\varphi _{2}$, do $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$ and $a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$ create different particles?

Can you use them together, e.g., $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\left|0\right>$?

If so, how many particles are created by $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\left|0\right>$?

What if $\phi_{2}(x)=2\phi_{1}(x)$?   Then $a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})=2a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$, which does *not* equal $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$.  What does $a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\left|0\right>$ create?

I'm asking these questions because nothing I've read yet even talks about this.  Answers would help, but I'd also appreciate any references you could cite of relevant material in textbooks, papers, or other resources.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like two distinct quantum fields $\varphi _{1}$ and $\varphi _{2}$ that solve K-G will in general have different associated creation and destruction operators, $a_{1}(\textbf{k})\neq a_{2}(\textbf{k})$ and $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\neq a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$.  That is, for a given 3-momentum $\textbf{k}$, there are different creation and destruction operators associated with different quantum fields.   Correct?

Yes, that is correct.

> For a given $\textbf{k}$, and different quantum fields $\varphi _{1}$ and $\varphi _{2}$, do $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$ and $a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$ create different particles?

Yes: the very definition of what it means for $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ to be different quantum fields is that they create different particles.

> Can you use them together, e.g., $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\left|0\right>$?

Yes.

> If so, how many particles are created by $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\left|0\right>$?

A particle of type 1 is created and a particle of type 2 is created for a total of two particles.

> What if $\phi_{2}(x)=2\phi_{1}(x)$?   Then $a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})=2a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$, which does *not* equal $a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})a_{1}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})$.  What does $a_{2}^{\dagger }(\textbf{k})\left|0\right>$ create?

I don't quite understand what you're asking here.  That would create a particle of type 2, but since you specified that $\phi_2 = 2\phi_1$, the two different fields aren't actually fields for different types of particles, so we could also say that it created a particle of type 1 because type 1 and type 2 are actually the same type.